# Error still occurs even after registering the required dependency, what is wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

The following code simulates the problem. I do register the dependency but errors still occur.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", ([FromServices] Foo f) =>
{
    f.Print();
    return "Hello World!";
});

app.Run();


public interface IFoo
{
    void Print();
}


public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Print()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Foo's Print()");
    }
}
```

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Foo' has been registered.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

I created the app with `dotnet new web -o MyProjectName`.

Comment: Change `Foo f` to `IFoo f`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: I see. Thank you. A very stupid mistake. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the signature of [`ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton<TService,TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addsingleton-2(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection)):

> `TService` - The type of the service to add.
> `TImplementation` - The type of the implementation to use.

You have registered `IFoo`, not `Foo` so resolve the interface:

```cs
app.MapGet("/", ([FromServices] IFoo f) =>
{
    f.Print();
    return "Hello World!";
});
```

P.S.

You should be able to skip the `FromServicesAttribute` because Minimal API handler support implicit [resolution from the DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#parameter-binding-with-dependency-injection), i.e. `(IFoo f) => ...` .

Answer (score 2):

You have register the service, but you ask for the wrong type. Try this instead, as you register type Foo as an implementation of the interface IFoo.

```
app.MapGet("/", ([FromServices] IFoo f) =>
{
    f.Print();
    return "Hello World!";
});
```